# Why 'react-router-dom' showing 'Cannot GET'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I've created simple web-application and try to hook up `react-router-dom`, when I launch application, it's showing component `Audience`(url: `localhost:3000`), but if I change url to `localhost:3000/board` or `localhost:3000/speaker` it show `Cannot GET /board` or `Cannot GET /speaker`

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import Audience from './components/Audience.jsx';
import Board from './components/Board.jsx';
import Speaker from './components/Speaker.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
<Router>
  <div>
    <Route path="/" component={Audience}/>
    <Route path="/board" component={Board}/>
    <Route path="/speaker" component={Speaker}/>
  </div>
</Router>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"><div>
```

Comment: How are you serving the files? You need to ensure that the webserver will return the same HTML file for all the URLs you mentioned.

Comment: Did you try using switch around you routes ? (look at this tutorial : https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf )